# JQuery Mobile Click inside controlgroup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to display a list of checkboxes within a controlgroup, that have a clickable image. However, the click event doesn't fire on a mobile, but works fine a browser.

From suggestions, I have tried to bind the event using bind/live/on and also tried using the 'touchstart' event.
In order for me to get the styling right, I have set the a-tag, with 'data-role="none"'.

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
  <fieldset id="lstProcedures" runat="server" data-role="controlgroup">
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk1' id='chk1' value='1' />
    <label for='chk1'> TEST
      <a href='#' data-role="none" style="float: right" id="test" onclick="alert('Hello'); event.stopPropagation(); return false;">
        <img src='/Images/pdf_icon32.png' alt='pdf'  />
      </a>
    </label>
  </fieldset>           
</div>
```

Better add my whole page to this, as I am not sure, where I have gone wrong:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lightgreen3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });

    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessageTheme = "a";
        $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = "Error!!!";
    });       
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonClicked(senderName) {
        var id = GetWorksheetID();
        switch (senderName) {
            case "Back":
                window.location = "../MDetails.aspx?ID=" + id;
                break;
        }
    }

    function GetWorksheetID() {
        var $tmp = $("#hdnField");
        return $tmp.val();
    }

     $(document).on("pageinit", "#procedures", function () {
            $("#lstProcedures > label > a").on("vclick", function () {
                alert("Hello");
                return false;
            });
        });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        parent.popup.SetHeaderText("Select Procedures");
    });

    function DisplayPDF(id) {
        // alert("Hello " + id);
        // window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
    }


</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnField" runat="server" />
<div data-role="page" id="procedures">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a href="#" id="btnBack" runat="server" data-role="button" onclick="ButtonClicked('Back')"
                    data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="top">Back </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="top" Text="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <fieldset id="lstProcedures" runat="server" data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend></legend>
            <input type='checkbox' name='chk1' id='chk1' value='1' />
            <label for='chk1'>
                TEST <a href='#'  style="float: right" data-role="none" id="test" onclick="alert('Hello')">
                    <img src='/Images/pdf_icon32.png' alt='pdf' />
                </a>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: what versions are you using? jq and jqm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an `onclick` attribute to register your handler, which is discouraged and only supports actual click events coming a pointing device. Mobile devices use different, "touch"-based events.

jQuery Mobile defines a virtualized event ([vclick](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)) that is triggered both by click and touch events. You can remove your `onclick` attribute and handle that event in the recommended, unobtrusive way:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#yourPageId", function() {
    $("#lstProcedures > label > a").on("vclick", function() {
        alert("Hello");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note that returning `false` from the handler is already equivalent to calling both `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` on the event, so you do not have to explicitly perform the call to `stopPropagation()` in our case.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried various combinations of your suggestion, and had a look at the documentation. For some reason it is still not working. No idea why not. :(

Comment: @Rune, if you replaced `yourPageId` with the id of your page element and your jQuery is recent enough to support `on()`, this should work (unless I'm missing something). Does the error console say anything?

Comment: I have added all my code, as I am not sure what is going on. As you will be able to see, I am using an onclick-event on another tag and it works perfectly throughout the my pages.

Comment: @Rune, there is a possibility that jQuery Mobile moves elements around when enhancing the check box, and the `"#lstProcedures > label > a"` selector doesn't match anything as a result. Try specifying `#test` instead, since that's the id of your link.

Comment: Ahhh. Off course. That fixes it. Thank you so much for your help. Saved me a few gray hairs. lol Actually changed '"#lstProcedures > label > a"' to '"#lstProcedures a"', and it works.